# Simplify $(a-b)⋅b + (b-a)⋅a $

Tags: linear-algebra

I have this expression for sum of two dot products:
$$(a-b)⋅b + (b-a)⋅a $$

Are there any rules for dot products I can use to simplify this?

Comment: dot product of sum of vectors is the sum of dot products...

Comment: @DonThousand Thanks! So this can be simplified to $2a⋅b - a⋅a - b⋅b$ right?

Comment: @LennyWhite Correct. And from there you can go even further, but that requires recognizing a pattern.

Comment: I'm not sure what the rule is called but can we use this rule $(a-b)^2 
= a^2 - 2ab + b^2$ for dot products and so further simplify this to $-(a-b)^2$

Comment: **Hint:** $b-a=-(a-b)$.

Comment: @MrPie So $(b-a)⋅a$ can be written as $-(a-b)⋅a$?

Comment: Precisely! $\therefore (a-b)\cdot b \color{red}{+(b-a)\cdot a} = (a-b)\cdot b \color{red}{-(a-b)\cdot a} = (a-b)(b-a)$. Now apply the same substitution again :)

Comment: @MrPie Awesome thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can also be written as $(a-b)\cdot b-(a-b)\cdot a=(a-b)\cdot(b-a)=-(a-b)^2$.